# use asynchronous functions for I/O-bound operations

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I was reading this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async which says that:

**For I/O-bound code, you await an operation which returns a Task or Task inside of an async method.**

I have two questions:

Q1- for I/O-bound code, does it mean we need to use `Task.Factory.StartNew(..., TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)` or `TaskCompletionSource`

Q2- I wrote a two simple console apps below to simulate I/O-bound code, is my approach correct?

```
class Program  //use Task.Factory.StartNew
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task = ReadFile();
        Console.WriteLine("Do other work");
        int total = await task;
        Console.WriteLine($"Read {total} lines");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task<int> ReadFile()
    {
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(new Func<int>(Read), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    static int Read()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000); // simulate read operation
        return 9999;        // 9999 lines has been read
    }
}
```

and

```
class Program  // use TaskCompletionSource
{
    static void  Main(string[] args)
    {
        var awaiter = ReadFile().GetAwaiter();
        Console.WriteLine("Do other work");
        awaiter.OnCompleted(() => Console.WriteLine($"Read {awaiter.GetResult()} lines"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static Task<int> ReadFile()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            tcs.SetResult(Read()); 

        }).Start();
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    static int Read()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000); // simulate read operation
        return 9999;        // 9999 lines has been read
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: I/O bound functions should have `async` methods. For example `System.IO`'s [`File.ReadAllTextAsync`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/File.cs#L681-L733), or `Stream`'s `WriteAsync`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q1- for I/O-bound code, does it mean we need to use `Task.Factory.StartNew(..., TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)` or `TaskCompletionSource`

No.

It means you use `async` and `await`.

> Q2- I wrote a two simple console apps below to simulate I/O-bound code, is my approach correct?

No.

I/O is not synchronous by nature, so using `Thread.Sleep` is an incorrect substitute for I/O work. I/O is asynchronous by nature, so the proper placeholder is `await Task.Delay`.

```
class Program  // use async/await
{
  static async Task Main(string[] args)
  {
    var task = ReadFileAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Do other work");
    var result = await task;
    Console.WriteLine($"Read {result} lines");
    Console.ReadLine();
  }

  static async Task<int> ReadFileAsync()
  {
    await Task.Delay(5000); // simulate read operation
    return 9999;            // 9999 lines has been read
  }
}
```

In the general I/O case, [there is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). This is why using `Thread.Sleep` throws everything off; it forces a thread to be used, when I/O doesn't need one.

Comment: Excellent answer as always. It’s worth noting that `async main` isn’t available till c#7. Without it, the answer is a little more complicated. (If you haven’t upgraded yet, you should!)

Comment: @Stephen Cleary Thanks a lot for your answer. Another question is: you don't know how long will the Read operation takes, could be more than 5 secs, so how does Task.Delay(...); works here, you don't know what number should put in the Delay method?

Comment: @secondimage: `Task.Delay` is a placeholder for "do the asynchronous work here." It shouldn't be in the final code at all; it will be replaced by the actual asynchronous work (e.g., reading a file asynchronously).